# Stripe PaymentMethodsActivity doesn't work properly

Tags: java, android, kotlin, stripe-payments, android-scroll

I use **`PaymentMethodsActivity`** to allow users to manage cards on android, but there is two problem:

https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/customer-information

1. After adding more cards, when appears scroll, "**`add new card`**" button becomes not visible.

*As you see now **Add new card** button is visible in the bottom*
[image]

*After adding one card again it becomes not visible and can't scroll to it* 
[image]

2. There is no edit button to edit or delete card, but it

Is this normal for stripe?

*Although this problems doesn't exist on IOS Api*

Answer (score 1):

Can you clarify what you mean by the first point?  The second point-- yes, that is expected.  The PaymentMethodsActivity doesn't currently support Deleting or Updating payment sources; however, the PaymentSession does.  So while you can do these operations, it means you have to roll your own UI.  Not ideal, but the Android implementation was released more recently and is still building out parity with the iOS implementation.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have added screenshots, please look that